# C#, Regex, ASCII Escape Characters - won't match

Tags: c#, regex, ascii

```
string pat12 = @"\e\[36m(.+)";
line2parse = "[36mA Rocky Landing";
if (Regex.Match(line2parse,pat12).Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ROOM NAME: "+Regex.Match(line2parse,pat12).Groups[1].ToString().Trim());
}
```

NOTE: You are unable to see the ESC sequence before the [36 in my variable "line2parse" but its there.  If I wanted to make it show up in Notepad++ I would hold down ALT and type "027" on the numpad. It then shows up as ESC in Notepad++.  In C# console it shows up as a left pointing arrow.  Ironically I can do "ALT + 27" and it shows that left arrow in Notepad++ (but if i add the 0, it does the ESC look instead of the arrow)

I am doing many Regex matches so the problem isn't with my Regex variable or anything like that.  I cannot get this to match properly despite it working at this site:  http://regexstorm.net/tester

At that site, this is the pattern:  "\e[36m(.+)" (without quotes) and this is the input: [36mA Rocky Landing (again you can't see the escape thing).  It then tells me $1 would be "A Rocky Landing" but in my actual code, it doesn't match.

What am I doing wrong?

I have looked through quite a few other, similar, posts and based on what they say, I believe this should work.  I even tried [^\x00-\x7F] as my escape char catch and it still wont match.

Comment: Could you please explain what you need to get in the end? `Escape Matched: [36mA Rocky Landing`? But your code is working then. Or just grab `A Rocky Landing?` Then [grab `match.Groups[1].Value`](https://ideone.com/2PM5ES).

Comment: Use unicode for ESC or any other non-visualized character in the string: `string pat12 = "\\e\u02B\\[36m(.+)";`

Comment: @Novaterata OP regex *works*, yours is different and does not even compile. Derek, please explain what you are doing.

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't understand the question then. I was trying to address the stuff in the NOTE. I guess I missed an escape. I wasn't offereing a solution, just a workaround for the whole ALT-27 ESC thing. You should not need to enter something into a string in C# with the ALT key

Comment: I am parsing a log file.  In the log file ASCII codes are there representing colors.  I can't show you exactly what it looks like because the ESC characters don't show on here, but Between 2 ascii tags are words.  I want to get the words between the 2 tags.  

I updated my OP to show exactly what I'm after.

My problem still remains which is, it never matches.

Comment: @DerekConlon Now, your `line2parse` has got no ESC symbol. If you add it, [it will still work](https://ideone.com/w3WSWg). Do you mean `\e` can be optional? Add `?` after `\e` then.

Comment: I now believe my problem has to do with it not being an actual escape.  I am not super familiar with ASCII and how it works, but in both Notepad, and Notepad++, ALT + 27 and ALT + 027 do different symbols.  I now believe that the regex \e matches ALT + 27 but will not match ALT + 027 despite both of them being labeled as "ESCAPE".  In notepad, ALT 27 does the arrow, but alt 027 does a black dot.  I need to figure out how to match ALT + 027 rather than ALT + 27.  Any help would be super appreciated

Comment: delete your question, it's not well formed

Comment: notepad++ has a plugin for looking at files in binary/hex, if you use that you will be able to see all your character codes

Comment: plugin is called "Hex-Editor"

Comment: Holy smokes. People still MUD?

Comment: Hex editor shows it as "1b" which is the ASCII equivalent of 27.  Nothing I do gets it to match anything, even when i hard code the Line2Parse to be exactly as it should be to match the regex, it still wont match.  I even put ALT + 27 into my C# code and it STILL won't match an escape character.

I've decided to just use .+ to match my ASCII escape characters.  Total failure, but it obviously should be working so its something I'm doing wrong.  I'll figure it out one day.  Thanks.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes, like 500 people still play MUD's.  I'm one of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think `\e` is the escape sequence for an escape character? You need to use `\x1b` instead.

```
string pat12 = @"\x1b\[36m(.+)";
```

Comment: This worked.  
Also, I think \e is the escape sequence for an escape character because of this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions

all this probably had something to do with my .txt file being the wrong "type" (meaning, ANSI, UNICODE, etc) 

Either way, my log file being as it sits,and me using \x1b instead of \e worked.

THANK YOU.

Comment: Interesting. A quick LINQPad test works with `\e` in the pattern to compare against `\x1b` in the string. There isn't a non-Unicode string type in C# so I wouldn't have though you could fail no matter how your file was formatting.

Comment: Another thing I noticed during these tests was, If I copied/pasted from my log file into a new .txt file, the little arrow pointing left is actually HALF the size of the arrow pointing left if i just manually type ALT 27.  as it turns out \e didn't detect either, but \1xb detected the "original" (with the smaller arrow).  The fact that those symbols appear as different sizes suggest to me that depsite all "tests" showing they are the same, SOMETHING was different and that something is breaking my attempts at using \e